# Kiosk chrome app: navigate to URL

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-app, kiosk-mode, google-chrome-os

I have built a Chrome App which needs to load some websites inside its own window.

The purpose is to display full-screen contents on TVs using Google Chromeboxes in Kiosk mode.

I can't use iframes as the content I must load doesn't allow it.

My researches led me to some code like :

```
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function(tab) {
    chrome.tabs.create({'url': event.target.href})
})
```

This seems to open a new tab on the browser running the extension, but not in the extension window.

The vision I have about chrome apps may be confused as it's the first I'm developing, please don't hesitate to tell me the basics I would not have heard of

Comment: Since you mention Kiosk mode and tagged your question as both Chrome App and Chrome Extension, I suspect you _really_ mean a Chrome App. But you need to confirm this / edit the question.

Comment: Yes, i'm talking about a chrome app. This distinction was unclear for me at the moment.
Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the [`<webview>` tag](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/tags/webview), available in Chrome Apps, to embed external content.

This does not trigger anti-framing protection, since from the point of view of web security each `<webview>` is a top-level browsing context.

Note the limitations of `<webview>`: some web features like message boxes or permission requests have to be implemented by you.

As an example of webview usage, see the [Browser sample app](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/chrome-app-samples/tree/master/samples/webview-samples/browser).